# Java arraylist questionn

Tags: java, arraylist

animals.java

```
public class animals{
    static ArrayList<animals> anV  = new ArrayList<animals>();
    static ArrayList<animals> anF = new ArrayList<animals>();
    ......
    ..
    .
}

public void metod1(String tur){
    ArrayList<animals> an;

    if(tur.equals("V")) an = anV;
    else           an = anF;

    for (animals data : an) {
        an.add(blah blah);
        ..........
    }
}
```

Add work normally but not add when tur == "V" then list to > anV. add to **an list, not anV**.

i change tur.equals but not work. because program add to an list, i want add to anV.

Comment: I imagine your are getting a ConcurrentModificationException. If that is the case, its because you have a `for` loop on a collection you are modifying.

Comment: `tur == "V"` should be `"V".equals(tur)`

Comment: change `tur == "V` to `tur.equals("V")` and it will work as you want! In Java objects should be compared using `equals()` method, not using `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` can be used to compare primitive types, such as `char`s and `int`s; but not a `String`, which is an `Object`. If you use it to compare `String`s, it will compare their references, not their contents.

Thus, to compare `String`s, use [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (tur.equals("V")) {

}
```

Also, you're adding elements to a `Collection` that you are iterating over. Are you sure there isn't a typo here?

```
for (animals data : an) {
    an.add(blah blah);
}
```

Comment: `==` can be used for comparison between all primitive types.

Comment: better would be to use `"V".equals(tur)`, this will avoid `NullPointerException`, if `tur` is null

Comment: @Nandkumar: That's what Yoda would use eheh.

Comment: if(tur == "V") System.out.println("V");if(tur.equals("V")) System.out.println("V"); all work but i want to say when i call method1("V") program add to list an,   i want to add to list anV

Comment: @user1429570: But what exactly do you want to add?

Comment: @João Silva, all code work normally but when run my programme my code work and add to list normally i show all element on **an**. not **anV**. but i write > **an** = **anV**; why add to an list. ( my english bad bad :D )

Comment: @user1429570: I'm sorry but I'm not following you. Are you sure that `tur.equals("V")`? Also, your current loop doesn't make much sense, what do you want to add to the `anV` list?

Comment: ok i solved problem. sytax problem sory all everybody thank for help

Answer (score 4):

```
if(tur == "V")
```

String comparison should use `eqauls()` instead of `==`

Unless Strings you are comparing are `String` literals.

Comment: You definitely mean `equals()`. :)

Comment: @E_net4: Yes, I do. Did I type something else? Thanks for editing.

Comment: It still says `eqauls` and the OP stated the behaviour changes on this value so its no the problem.

Comment: @user1429570: Sorry to say, but I couldn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: I take `work normally but not add when tur == "V"` to mean that this test is working for him, otherwise it would make no difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I guess work normally means, it is not throwing any errors. It is little bit hard to decipher OP English. if "tur" is not literal, I guess tur=="V" won't result in true (except very rare cases).